# select the latest row based on sysdate and/or other conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

im trying to find the latest row from a table but the row must include either conditions which is status = 'FAILED' or (end_time <> sysdate or end_time <> sysdate-1). I want it to return no rows if either conditions are met, but it is showing me the latest row of the table when both conditions are not met.

Below is the query I'm working, can anyone tell if its right or wrong and how would I go about this?

```
 select session_key, start_time, end_time, status
 from v$rman_backup_job_details
 where end_time = (select max(end_time) from v$rman_backup_job_details
                   where status = 'FAILED' or end_time <> sysdate or end_time <> sysdate-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need create a query like this:

```
select 
    session_key, 
    start_time, 
    end_time, 
    status 
from 
    v$rman_backup_job_details
where 
    end_time = (
            select max(end_time) from v$rman_backup_job_details
                 where status = 'FAILED' AND (end_time <> sysdate or end_time <> sysdate-1)
    ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

To return only the last result. I put the AND because is required to your clausule the FAILED status.

Comment: my bad I didn't phrase the question correctly, it is supposed to return the latest row based on either status='FAILED' or the end_time <> sysdate/sysdate-1. I have updated the question.

Comment: In a fast check, i think your query are correct. I just put the where ROWNUM = 1 to return only the first record (if you have 2 or more with the same date)